# Passing reference to map element as argument

Tags: c++, oop, unordered-map

I've got two classes:

```
class Container
{
    /* ... */

    // Type 'PersonDetails' is a struct.
    std::unordered_map<unsigned int, PersonDetails> AllDetails;
};
```

and

```
class Person
{
public:
    Person(THE_ARGUMENT);
};
```

Not let's say that the class `Container` changes the contents of `AllDetails` dynamically. In my `main` function I construct one object of `Container` and a lot off `Person`. Each `Person` object has a unique id (which is the key of `AllDetails`), but I do *not* want to pass it as an argument to the constructor of `Person`. Instead I want to pass a **direct reference** to the map's element that is going to be valid all the time.

I thought of passing an iterator but it's highly possible for it to be invalidated during updates or while adding mappings to `AllDetails`.

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are looking for with (pseudo) code ? Its quite unclear.

Comment: Why don't you want to pass the unique ID to the `Person` constructor? That seems like the best way to me.

Comment: The reason iterators can be invalidated is because the map can rearrange memory on its own, and that's true no matter how you capture the reference. It's not because the designers of the iterator wanted to make life harder for you -- it can change because that's a functional requirement of dealing with maps. You can pass the address however you like, but the map can still move the object behind your back. I agree, you should really just store the ID and do the lookup as needed.

Comment: If you want stable iterators, use a node-based class such as `std::map`.

Comment: Also, `unordered_map`'s inserts can invalidate iterators, but not references (and pointers) to elements, so you can also store a pointer directly if you want.

Comment: Neihter iterators nor pointers or references are usable (may be invalidated as the map/hashtable grows). Are you looking for unique ID? Make it static atomic<int>.

Comment: firda, as T.C. said, only iterators can be invalidated. References to elements remain valid in call cases, even after a rehash.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

struct PersonDetails 
{
    PersonDetails()
        : Age(0)
    {}

    std::string Name;
    int Age;
};

class Container
{
    /* ... */
public:
    typedef std::map<unsigned int, PersonDetails> PersonDetailsMap;
    typedef PersonDetailsMap::value_type          PersonDetailsElement;

    PersonDetailsElement& GetDetails(unsigned int ID)
    {
        auto it = AllDetails.lower_bound(ID);
        if (it != AllDetails.end() && !AllDetails.key_comp()(ID, it->first))
            return *it;
        else
            return *AllDetails.insert(it, std::make_pair(ID, PersonDetails()));
    }

    // Type 'PersonDetails' is a struct.
    std::map<unsigned int, PersonDetails> AllDetails;
};

class Person
{
public:

    Container::PersonDetailsElement& Details;

    Person(Container::PersonDetailsElement& details)
        : Details(details)
    {}
};

int main()
{
    Container c;

    using namespace std;
    vector<shared_ptr<Person>> people;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
    {
        people.push_back(make_shared<Person>(c.GetDetails(i)));
        people.back()->Details.second.Age = 10 + i;
        people.back()->Details.second.Name = string("Bob");

        assert(people.back()->Details.first == i);
        assert(c.AllDetails[i].Age == 10 + i);
        assert(c.AllDetails[i].Name == string("Bob"));
    }
}
```